# .bash_profile ldapsearch function not outputting to terminal

Tags: linux, function, output, bash

I have a bash function in my .bash_profile that is not returning results to the terminal.
When I run the command as normal via the CLI results are returned.

```
ldap_check_cleaup () 
{
ldapsearch -LLL -h itdsvbms.SomeDomain.org -p 389 \
    -D "uid=SomeUser,o=SomeDomain.org" -w SomePassWord -b "ou=People,o=SomeDomain.org"  \
    -s sub '(&(ReservedRMAliases=$1)(!(RMid=*))(RMAliasUpdateDate=12/01/2012 19:02:00)(RMAliasStatus=IN)(status=IN))' |  \
        tee /dev/tty  
}
```

running *ldap_check_clenaup TestRecord* returns no output when executed from the bash prompt. *TestRecord* does exist and when the following command  is run from the CLI, the correct record is returned:

```
ldapsearch -LLL -h itdsvbms.SomeDomain.org -p 389 -D "uid=SomeUser,o=SomeDomain.org" \
    -w SomePassWord -b "ou=People,o=SomeDomain.org" \
    -s sub '(&(ReservedRMAliases=TestRecord)(!(RMid=***))(RMAliasUpdateDate=12/01/2012 19:02:00)(RMAliasStatus=IN)(status=IN))' | \
        tee /dev/tty`
```

The lack of out put only happens when I try to use this ldapsearch and the arguments as a bash function.

I think this may be related to using ' instead of " for the attribute (!(RMid=*)) but I am unsure, please help.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by piping the output to `tee /dev/tty`?

Comment: If I remove tee /dev/tty same lack of out put.  I was attempting to force the redirection to the terminal via tty

Comment: (I've taken the liberty to format the code, and also adding some bash line breaks for better readablility. Hope I didn't mess up anything.)

Comment: You have an interesant nick...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use double-quotes around the argument that contains `$1`. Variable interpolation is not performed inside single-quoted strings.

Comment: Spot on!  replaced the ' with the " in .bash_profile and worked like a charm.  It's odd because in the CLI when I issue the command with a ", I get "-bash: !: event not found" returned for the ldapsearch querry.   What would is causing the difference in behavior in the cli vs the bash function?

Comment: I just read the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash post you referenced.  How would one handle a * in double quotes then in this case at the CLI?  I try to keep my functions an CLI use as similar as possible.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything special. When a `*` is inside double quotes, filename globbing won't be performed and the `*` will be passed to the program (as I believe is the desired result in this case).